Science fiction animated movie where the protagonist traveled in time to defeat the big bad
I have watched this movie at the beginning of the nineties, It was probably released somewhen around that time. What I remember from the movie:
The protagonist lived in a country which was oppressed by invading soldiers in some futuristic suits.
He managed to arrive to the invaders leader. That leader was some kind of a living structure, or maybe he was just enormously big. For sure there's a scene where the protagonist is on a red(?) scaly(?) floor and that floor is part of the leader.
The protagonist wants to kill/destroy the leader, but he/it tells him that it's pointless/impossible(?) now and convinces the protagonist to travel to the past to kill the leader while he/it was still young. The protagonist does travel to the past and meet the leader but I don't remember how their meeting ends.
At some point during the movie the protagonist meets a group of radically mutated outcasts. Each one is different. One has extra heads on the chest where breasts would be, if I recall correctly. These mutants call themselves Transmuters and their motto is "I was. I will be. I am not." because they were normal humans in the past and hope to be normal again in the future.
The protagonist eventually learns that those who invaded his real are his compatriots that were transformed by the aforementioned leader. I remember that transformation involved time travel. Either he/it took people from the future, converted them, and send to the past, or it was the other way round.
I have watched this movie in the Polish version. Transmuters name and their motto were translated back to English from a Polish translation so probably those didn't sound exactly like above.

Now let's close the old one as duplicate. ;-)

@Walt Is it a good idea to edit the direction of time travel I have mixed up?

No need to change that. It's an honest mistake and you've done well to remember that much of a film you've seen more than 20 years ago, so well done. :)

Ok, so I just changed the title a bit

You're looking for the animated sci-fi film Gandahar (AKA Light Years) from 1988.

Ganhadar is an idyllic paradise where it's people have mastered both themselves and their environment. Everything exists in perfect harmony with the world, providing enlightenment for both the body and soul. Paradise is lost when a malevolent force begins to attack the outlying regions of the planet, attacking small villages and turning their people into stone. Sylvain is dispatched by the Council of Women to find out what is menacing the peaceful world. He is later attacked by strange bird-like creatures, rendering him unconscious when it falls on him. He wakes up in the presence of deformed figures, who are not the enemy, but instead mutated products of ancient scientists, perhaps during the search to perfect everything. He escapes and watches metallic drones, who are the attackers, passing through a metal doorway of some sort. From here he discovers the Metamorphisis, a gargantuan brain mass. He returns to the capital with Arielle, but not too soon to find it being attacked by the Men of Metal. The Metamorphisis and the Men of Metal are from a thousand years in the future. Sylvain is placed in suspended animation for a millenium, while the Metamorphisis destroys the world. When he wakes up, the Metamorphisis has become a sick, evil thing. It's cells have degraded and the stone people are brought into the future, re-animated, and then killed off to be used in the brain tissue. Sylvain must destroy the brain in order to change history, but is it possible?

Everything you wrote is there (including the mutant with eyes on his chest) with the sole exception that Sylvain is sent to the future to kill the villain (then returns to the past). Here's a clip [Warning: Nudity]:



